# How to i check knockout rendering time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i have complex page, where i am displaying lots of information based on javascript array

i wanted to see. how much time it took for knockout.js to binding data!

what i did is :

```
   var V0 = performance.now();
```

this line binding data to html :                         `ItemData.ViewModels.VehicleResults(searchResponse.ItemResults.Items);`

```
 var V1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Display Objects :- ItemResults took " + (V1 - V0) + " milliseconds.")
```

surprised result i get is it took :2000 miliseconds, which i felt too much!

so question is : is there anything out there, where i can findout my knockout took this much time to display data on html

Comment: Just curious why do you feel that 2000ms is too much, if you see an apparent lag for example it may be true. Say if you have a 1000 items with  complicated view models in a table it sounds quite plausible.

Comment: Olga, i wanted to make under 500 ms ! that is requirement

Comment: You didn't specify it in your question. I see, fair enough. Could you tell us what binding you use, knockout version, item example and how many items you approximately have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use console.time

```
console.time("myscript");
// ... your code.
console.timeEnd("myscript");
```

Comment: what is "myscript" ? and how the console.time and timeend is different from what i wrote ?

Comment: _"myscript"_ is a string literal.

Comment: console.time("what is the use of this?");

Comment: It could any string but should be unique value for time and timeEnd method to calculate the time difference in between.